# How to use VB to create Excel style and format data sheet?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to write a program which will replace my current paper based record. My current paper record is basically many column and rows with different width, height, and other properties. I know how to write a VB program that can save the information, but I don't know how to make the VB program to generate a xls datasheet to which would exactly like my paper record.

Would someone please give me the information about that?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are interested in Interop then see this link http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439.
It is very easy to use and integrates flawlessy in vb.net.
I am not providing code as a sample because the samples which are included in the package are very good.

***As a hint: Internally I would use a `Data-Table` to store your values and then use a separate module to load/store it to excel.***

Answer (score 0):

An excel file could be thougth as a simple database where each sheet is a different table.
Assuming you have Excel on your machine, you could create an empty XLS file and then use OleDB to fill the worksheets.

```
Sub WriteToExcel()
    Dim con As String con = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                            "Data Source=C:\temp\test.xls;" & _
                            "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;'"
    Using c as OleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(con))
        c.Open()
        Dim commandString as String = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (F1, F2, F3) " & _
                                      "values('Column1Text', 'Column2Text', 'Column3Text')" 
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(commandString))
            cmd.Connection = c
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
   End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

other options include OpenXml (which I'd have thought is the "recommended" way to do it but which brings with it a learning curve) or at the other end of the scale (in terms of crudeness) write your data in a comma-separated (csv) format and manually import it into Excel